# Проверить входит ли множество А в множество В. Множества представлены одномерными массивами

Tags: c++, массивы, математика, stl, множества

Программа посредством алгоритма типа слияния определяет результат операции вхождение и выдает его на экран с необходимыми пояснениями. Под пояснением понимается вывод сообщения "A входит в B" или "A не входит в B".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int n, p, m = 0;
    cout << "\n Введите количество элементов в множестве А: "; 
    cin >> n;
    int* A = new int[n];
    cout << "\n Введите количество элементов в множестве B: ";
    cin >> p;
    int* B = new int[p];
    //Множество А
    cout << "\n Введите элементы множества А: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    cout << "\n Множество А: ";
    // Удаляем повторяющиеся элементы
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (A[i] == A[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < n; k++)
                    A[k] = A[k + 1];
                n--;
                j--;
            }
    // Сортируем по возрастанию
    for (int k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
            {
                int tmp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    // Выводим множество
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    //Множество B
    cout << endl << "\n Введите элементы множества B: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
    {
        cin >> B[i];
    }
    cout << "\n Множество B: ";

    // Удаляем повторяющиеся элементы
    for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < p; j++)
            if (B[i] == B[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < p; k++)
                    B[k] = B[k + 1];
                p--;
                j--;
            }
    // Сортируем по возрастанию
    for (int t = p - 1; t >= 0; t--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < t; ++j)
        {
            if (B[j] > B[j + 1])
            {
                int tmp = B[j];
                B[j] = B[j + 1];
                B[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    // Выводим множество
    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
    {
        cout << B[i] << " ";
    }
    // Проверка вхождения множества А в множество В 


    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Первое и главное - вы похвастаться? Вопроса я тут не вижу... И - как насчет повторяющихся элементов - что сказано *в условии*? И что сказано - раз С++ - об использовании возможностей стандартной библиотеки? Или только через указатели, массивы и вручную?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как это реализовать? В исходных массивах повторяющиеся элементы уже удалены

Comment: Если они отсортированы - все очень просто, идем снизу и сравниваем... но вам точно нельзя использовать `set`? Или хотя бы `set_difference`?

Comment: Set использовать можно, но я не полностью разобрался, поэтому решил реализовывать через массивы

Comment: Достаточно просто перебирать все элементы массива A и во вложенном цикле сравнивать с элементами B. Как только какой-то из A не найден в B, можно сделать вывод -- не входит. Т.е. в этом конкретном случае (однократно сделать такую операцию) все остальные действия (удаление повторов и сортировка) избыточны

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если можно использовать `set` и стандартную библиотеку, я бы делал так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> A, B;
    int n, m;
    cout << "\nВведите количество элементов в множестве А: "; 
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\nВведите количество элементов в множестве B: ";
    cin >> m;
    //Множество А
    cout << "\nВведите элементы множества А: ";
    for (int x, i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        A.insert(x);
    }
    cout << "\nМножество А: ";
    // Выводим множество
    for(int i: A) cout << i << " ";
    //Множество B
    cout << endl << "\nВведите элементы множества B: ";
    for (int x, i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        B.insert(x);
    }
    cout << "\nМножество B: ";
    // Выводим множество
    for(int i: B) cout << i << " ";
    // Проверка вхождения множества А в множество В 

    if (includes(B.begin(),B.end(),A.begin(),A.end()))
        cout << "\n\nA входит в B\n";
    else
        cout << "\n\nA не входит в B\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вроде разобрался